# how to make program that be in the taskbar windows-CE

Tags: c#, windows-ce

how to make C# program that will be All time in the taskbar ?

i want to Build a Keyboard program.

i need that when i open the device the program will open and be in the taskbar.

another question is, when i have an external program that has a Textbox, how

to make that when i press any key in my C# keyboard it will be in this external Textbox ?

thank's in advance

Comment: By taskbar, do you mean System Tray?  As for taskbar http://www.coolnerds.com/XP/Taskbar/xpTaskbar.htm>, a C# windows form project will by default display in the windows taskbar.

Comment: @Michael: This is Windows CE, not XP.

Comment: Yep, the requester noted that in my post and I corrected it....thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not implemented in the CF, but the NotifyIcon class is what you're after.  [The SDF](https://github.com/ctacke/sdf) does [implement it](https://github.com/ctacke/sdf).  It would be used something like this:

```
m_notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon();
m_notifyIcon.Icon = this.Icon;
m_notifyIcon.Visible = true;
m_notifyIcon.Click += new EventHandler(m_notifyIcon_Click);
m_notifyIcon.DoubleClick += new EventHandler(m_notifyIcon_DoubleClick);
```

**EDIT**

If you want to implement this yourself, the place to start is with the [Shell_NotifyIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa922175.aspx) API.  You'll want to pass it the handle to a [MessageWindow class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsce.forms.messagewindow(VS.80).aspx) and handle the WM_NOTIFY messages.

Comment: The SDF Community Edition is free to use and distribute.  The code above uses it and is free.  How much more free are you after?

Comment: Is it possible to adapt to delete an icon left by *another* application?

Answer (score 2):

To Create a system Tray application in Windows-CE, put some code like:

```
CSystemTray m_TrayIcon;   // Member variable of some class

... 
// in some member function maybe...

m_TrayIcon.Create(pParentWnd, WM_MY_NOTIFY, "Click here", 
                  hIcon, nTrayIconID);
```

Eg. For a non-MFC tray icon, do the following:

```
Collapse
CSystemTray m_TrayIcon;   // Member variable of some class

... 
// in some member function maybe...

m_TrayIcon.Create(hInstance, NULL, WM_MY_NOTIFY, 
                  "Click here", hIcon, nID);

// Send all menu messages to hMyMainWindow

m_TrayIcon.SetTargetWnd(hMyMainWindow);
```

As found here:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/systemtray.aspx

To create a system tray application in Windows XP or Windows 7/Vista, put some code like this in your project:

```
private void Form1_Resize(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   if (FormWindowState.Minimized == WindowState)
      Hide();
}
```

and this to handle the system tray click

```
private void notifyIcon1_DoubleClick(object sender,
                                     System.EventArgs e)
{
    Show();
    WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
}
```

This and more information found at :

http://www.developer.com/net/net/article.php/3336751/C-Tip-Placing-Your-C-Application-in-the-System-Tray.htm