# NotifyIcon (aka TrayIcon) in .NET Compact Framework 3.5

Tags: c#, vb.net, compact-framework, windows-ce, trayicon

I am developing a simple tray icon application which required to run in .NET Compact Framework 3.5 (will be deploy in Windows CE 6).

Unfortunately "NotifyIcon" component was not supported in Compact version.

Does anyone have any solutions or code samples which I can refer to?

What I need is to run the application in tray icon mode and popup a menustrip when detected mouse right-click on the icon

[image]

Comment: This requires pinvoke.  They even used it in a [.NET CF tutorial about pinvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446529.aspx).

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853746/how-to-make-program-that-be-in-the-taskbar-windows-ce